# Создание модели ADO NET из файла базы данных SDB

Tags: c#, база-данных

Есть файл БД с расширением SDB. Как его подключить в Visual Studio и создать из не модель, для последующей полноценной работы через Linq

Comment: А какой БД принадлежит данный формат файлов? OpenOffice.org Base Database File или MonKey Office SQLite Database File?

Comment: Не знаю, а как мне это проверить?

Comment: Поинтересоваться у источника откуда вы получили этот файл.

Comment: Этот файл БД данный ПО складского учета. Им я писал, они не отвечают. Программа  StoreHouse  для складского учета. Разработка компании UCS

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ucs.ru/products/r_keeper/storehouse/) пишут, что данные можно выгрузить в 1C, а значит, вероятно, в SQL Server. А дальше на основе имеющейся базы SQL Server можно с пом. Entity Framework быстро создать классы модели.

Comment: Думаю там имеется ввиду только те данные, которые необходимы для этих видов документов, а мне нужна вся БД. Буду пробывать. В любом случае, спасибо, что откликнулись!